# MS Access / SQL Server pass-through query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, pass-through

My query does run, but returns no results:

```
SET NoCount ON

SELECT 
   Inventory.EffectiveDate, 
   Inventory.Quantity, 
   Inventory.SourceType,
   Inventory.PickingLocation, 
   Inventory.SourceInventory,
   Locations.LocationId,
   Customers.CustomerName,
   Products.ProductId,
   LocationFrom.LocationId as lFrom,
   LocationTo.LocationId as lTo

FROM (((((((dbo.Inventory AS Inventory

   LEFT JOIN dbo.Products AS Products ON  Products.Product = Inventory.Product )
   LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS Locations ON Locations.Location = Inventory.Location )
   LEFT JOIN dbo.Customers AS Customers ON Customers.ConsignmentLocation = Inventory.Location )

   LEFT JOIN dbo.Inventory AS SourceLocation ON SourceLocation.Inventory = Inventory.SourceInventory)
   LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS LocationFrom ON LocationFrom.Location = SourceLocation.Location )

   LEFT JOIN dbo.Inventory AS TargetLocation ON TargetLocation.Inventory = Inventory.TargetInventory)
   LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations AS LocationTo ON LocationTo.Location = TargetLocation.Location)

WHERE  
    (Inventory.SourceType = 'Q' OR Inventory.SourceType = 'G' OR Inventory.SourceType = 'P' OR Inventory.SourceType = 'A' OR Inventory.SourceType = 'B') 
    AND 
    ((Inventory.EffectiveDate >= 2011-12-30 And Inventory.EffectiveDate <= 2011-12-31));
```

This query runs from Excel fine. But I was looking for the tool to be able to see tables, that's why I'm using Access - but it gives me more problems....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your date parameters with single quotes.

```
Inventory.EffectiveDate >= '2011-12-30'
```

You should also consider using shorter aliases to make the code more concise. I'm not sure of the purpose of using an alias like `Products` to represent `dbo.Products`... you should also eliminate all the unnecessary parentheses if Access doesn't force them on you.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
   inv.EffectiveDate, 
   inv.Quantity, 
   inv.SourceType,
   inv.PickingLocation, 
   inv.SourceInventory,
   loc.LocationId,
   cust.CustomerName,
   prod.ProductId,
   lFrom.LocationId as lFrom,
   lTo.LocationId as lTo
FROM  dbo.Inventory AS inv
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Products  AS prod  ON prod.Product   = inv.Product
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Locations AS loc   ON loc.Location   = inv.Location
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Customers AS cust  ON inv.Location   = cust.ConsignmentLocation
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Inventory AS src   ON src.Inventory  = inv.SourceInventory
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Locations AS lFrom ON lFrom.Location = src.Location
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Inventory AS trg   ON trg.Inventory  = inv.TargetInventory
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Locations AS lTo   ON lTo.Location   = trg.Location
WHERE  
    inv.SourceType IN ('Q', 'G', 'P', 'A', 'B') 
    AND inv.EffectiveDate >= '2011-12-30' 
    AND inv.EffectiveDate <= '2011-12-31'; -- suspect you want < '2012-01-01' here
    -- unless your column doesn't store time.
```

Comment: it's actually the other way around. if i put them in quotes i get this error: `the conversion of char data type to smalldaretime resulted in out-of-range value`

Comment: What is the data type of `Inventory.EffectiveDate`? What if you use `YYYYMMDD` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: you guided me to the right direction! apparently it should look like `'30/12/11'` thank you!

Comment: and yes access force me to use brackets. and db name is much longer than i put in here...

Comment: That doesn't seem right - `'30/12/11'`? Something is wrong there for sure. And it will be even more confusing for things like `'10/12/11'` - yuck